# Copious Android log output from Looper/Handler

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-handler, android-looper

I am getting ***copious*** output in my Android logs, and not from my app. (They persist after uninstall.) As you can see, the culprit might be Google Play Services.

The following block of text repeats nine total times (each with a different number in the brackets) in the millisecond labeled as `09-28 11:34:44.281`, appears again at `~.286`, and repeats with no obvious cause or relief:

```
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  : Handler (agdz) {8058183} sendMessageAtTime() called with no mQueue
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  : java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (agdz) {8058183} sendMessageAtTime() called with no mQueue
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  :  at jlw.sendMessageAtTime(:com.google.android.gms:111)
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  :  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  :  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  :  at android.database.ContentObserver.dispatchChange(ContentObserver.java:198)
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  :  at android.database.ContentObserver.access$000(ContentObserver.java:27)
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  :  at android.database.ContentObserver$Transport.onChange(ContentObserver.java:231)
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  :  at android.database.IContentObserver$Stub.onTransact(IContentObserver.java:62)
09-28 11:34:44.281  1035  1156 W Looper  :  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

In all of the instances (at least the ones I examined), the only difference is the string inside the brackets. All else, including the details of the stack trace, remain the same.

A Google Search finds only one similar instance — some obscure and unrelated log file in Cyanogen's JIRA project.

I just want to get rid of the cause. It's not enough to simply filter my logcat output because there is so much output that the whole thing slows down.

Any help I'm sure will be rewarded with my monster upvote.